# What is "almost-grown cologne"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, books

> ***And when I was thirteen***
>
> Shawn welcomed me into teenage life
> with a spritz of his almost-grown cologne,
> said my girlfriend—
>       my first girlfriend—
> would like it.
>
> But she hated it
> so I broke up with her,
> because
>
> to me
>
> her nose was
> funny acting.
>
> — from *Long Way Down* by Jason Reynolds, pub Simon & Schuster 2017

What does the phrase "almost-grown cologne" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means "cologne for someone who is almost a grown-up". A teenager might put on cologne, thinking that it will make them seem more like an adult and attractive to girls.

But in this poem, it actually annoyed his girlfriend. Rather than take it as a hint that he was trying too hard or used too much (a common error if you're not used to wearing fragrances), he concluded it was a problem with her ("her nose was funny acting"), and broke up with her.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that fragrances aimed at teenagers tend to be significantly sweeter and cheaper than those for adults.

Comment: I didn't even know there were such targeted fragrances. I thought the author might have been somewhat sarcastic -- a teenager might put on his father's cologne, thinking it would make him seem grown up.

Comment: No, there are *some* unisex fragrances, sprays, that are cheap and cheerful. Some products have a more youthful spin, and can be pricey while those aimed at girls can smell very floral–I mean that's what I remember seeing in perfumeries when I used to splash out on my favourite brands.

Comment: Seems more likely that there are perfumes for girls than colognes for boys, but I know very little about the life of teens these days.